# Is there a way to reset a UWP app using powershell?

Tags: powershell, uwp

I see that there are way to Get `Get-AppxPackage` or Remove `Remove-AppxPackage` UWP app from windows 10 using PowerShell.

I am wondering if there is a way to reset a UWP app? I require it for automated testing, I would rather reset the UWP app than uninstall and install again, as that would slow down the testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to clear your package's ApplicationData then you want

```
appdata = Windows.Management.Core.ApplicationDataManager.CreateForPackageFamily(pkgfamilyname)
appdata.ClearAsync()
```

See MSDN for [ApplicationDataManager.CreateForPackageFamily()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.core.applicationdatamanager.createforpackagefamily) and [.ClearAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.clearasync)

Powershell has no 'await' affordance last time I looked (though it's been a while) so not so viable. If you're looking to muck with applicationdata you may find [APPDATA.EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596669/is-there-a-way-to-reset-a-uwp-app-using-powershell) handy. You can probably guess why I wrote it... :P For instance

```
APPDATA.EXE Clear foo.bar_1234567890abc
```

If you're looking to reset a package to its initially installed state, then no, there is no API other than uninstall + install

```
Remove-AppxPackage foo.bar_1.2.3.4_x86__1234567890abc
Add-AppxPackage foobar.msix
```

Settings' Reset option for an installed package essentially does that just slightly more efficiently. You're still going thru the full deregister and uninstall the package and then install and register it for the user so it may not be instantaneous. But that's the only way to truly reset a package to its initial state. Windows has various forms of user data associated with a package (ApplicationData, IndexDB, more) as well as system state cribbed and wired up when a package is installed for a user (what is the package, where's it live, that the user has it, that it's status is not tampered or otherwise unhealthy, more). The only way to truly 'reset' that to the initial state is a full remove then add.

If you just need to wipe appdata then .ClearAsync is the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any command that would do that for you (except for the UI available in Settings app). However, you may write a PowerShell script that would clear up the application data files in the app's folder (this is not an official solution, but seems to work based on my trials).

Go to

```
C:\Users\{your_username}\AppData\Local\Packages\
```

And find your app's folder there. There are several folders containing the application state.

The nuclear option is to just delete all the folders. Then the app will crash once on startup, then the system will automatically reset it and restore the folders.

The less invasive option I have now tried seems to be to keep the folders and just delete their content, except for the `AC` folder, which seems to be system protected. When I tried this with my app, it launched successfully without crashing and system recreated the state files anew on its own.

The rest of application files lives in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`, but those are just application DLLs and content files and are read-only, so they should not affect the app state at all.

You may want to perform additional deletion if you use a [shared publisher folder](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/05/24/sharing-your-local-app-data/).

Answer (score -1):

For windows 10 build 2004+ there seems to be a powershell command `Reset-AppxPackage` now.

UPDATE

My mistake, it is available from [version 20175](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2020/07/22/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-20175/) onward. So, should be available in 20H2.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 version 2004 and I `Reset-AppxPackage` is not a recognized command.

Comment: My mistake, I thought it was already in 2004. However, it is coming in 20H2.